# Send E-mail through outlook via Excel VBA - convert string to currency format or percent

Tags: email, excel, number-formatting, vba

New to the site and very new to programming/VBA.

I work for a sales company, and I would like to send a basic email to each of our reps letting them know their monthly sales v goal and the percent of Goal

Here is my (very basic) code
I need 'May_Sales' and 'May_Goal' to be formatted as currency and 'May_Percent' to be formatted as a percent with 2 decimal places (16.14%)

```
' SendMassEmail Macro
'
row_number = 1

Do
DoEvents
    row_number = row_number + 1
    Dim mail_body_message As String
    Dim full_name As String
    Dim May_Sales As String
    Dim May_Goal As String
    Dim May_Percent As String

mail_body_message = "Good morning replace_name_here!" & vbNewLine & "Your Total Sales for May 2015 are May_Sales_replace" & vbNewLine & "Your Total Goal for May 2015 is May_Goal_replace" & vbNewLine & "You are currently at May_Percent_replace of your May Goal" & vbNewLine & "Thanks," & vbNewLine & "John Angerami"
full_name = Sheet1.Range("B" & row_number)
May_Sales = Sheet1.Range("C" & row_number)
May_Goal = Sheet1.Range("D" & row_number)
May_Percent = Sheet1.Range("E" & row_number)

mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "replace_name_here", full_name)
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "May_Sales_replace", May_Sales)
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "May_Goal_replace", May_Goal)
mail_body_message = Replace(mail_body_message, "May_Percent_replace", May_Percent)

Call SendEmail(Sheet1.Range("A" & row_number), "Daily Sales " & Sheet1.Range("F1"), mail_body_message)


Loop Until row_number = 2

'End Sub
```

Comment: Well done, for your first question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use the `Format` function in VBA.

Example:

`Format(May_Sales,"Currency")`
`Format(May_Percent,"0.00%")`

Comment: Thanks! Won't that just format it in the worksheet? I need it formatted in the E-mail.

Comment: @JohnAngerami, if it worked then please mark it as the answer to inform future visitors to the site.